# cakephp form data , sessions and reusing a view between 2 methods in same controller

Tags: php, cakephp

Newbie php question

I have a textbox where a user searches for something and a bunch of results are returned (search() method in the controller) when i click on a link, i want some more information to be
displayed (searchMore() method in controller).

Questions

1) How can I go back to the the same search.ctp page instead of creating a new search_more.ctp ? Use elements or php includes ? Use redirects ?
2) How can I retain the user input data on the text box when I go back there from searchMore() ? Does cakephp provide any helpers for sessions and such ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like a [pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/view/164/Pagination) problem.The easiest solution would be,paginate your search results only two pages using the [Paginator Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/164/Pagination),then you can easily switch them to each other.Another approach is [Ajax solution](http://book.cakephp.org/view/208/AJAX) which paginates like Twitter.

**Update:**(you'd better make your answer as a comment.)

Well,If I understand you correctly,you have same controler ,same search conditions,but you put them in diffrent actions while you need them use same view file.

**For question 1)**,it can be done by using functin [render](http://book.cakephp.org/view/428/render)

```
    $this->render('search');
```

in your more_search action.

**For question 2)**,you can pass the user's input data as parameters between the two actions,or you can store them in [session](http://book.cakephp.org/view/398/Methods).

But it looks quite a bit odd.As far as I can see,a better solution is doing your work in one action since you have the same condition and the same output format.Then it will be a work about pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm often doing stuff like this - like the insert records mechanism in PhpMyAdmin (start again with 25 records).

In `searchMore()`, use `$this->render('search');` That will send you back to the original view. Pass a variable like:

`$this->set('searchMore',true);` in your `searchMore()` method.

In the view, use a conditional (`if($searchMore){...}`), if required, to display alternate HTML in the view as required.